# How do you store a block of XML in ANT?

Tags: ant, mxml, flash-builder, mxmlc

I'm very new to ANT and have started using it in a Flash Builder project.

When I run the compiler I need to pass in some library paths. The whole thing looks like this:

```
<mxmlc 
    file="${SOURCE_DIR}/com/${PACKAGE_NAME}/Main.as"
    output="${RELEASE_DIR}/assets/swf/${IDENTIFIER}/main.swf"
    locale="${LOCALE}"
    static-rsls="false"
    accessible="true"
>
    <compiler.debug>false</compiler.debug>
    <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>
    <source-path path-element="${SOURCE_DIR}"/>
    <external-library-path file="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs/player/10.0/playerglobal.swc" append="true"/>
    <library-path file="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs/flash-integration.swc" append="true"/>
    <library-path file="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs/flex.swc" append="true"/>
    <library-path file="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs/utilities.swc" append="true"/>
    <library-path dir="${basedir}/libs" includes="*" append="true"/>

</mxmlc>
```

Basically everything after the output= part could be stored in some fashion and reused for all the other compilations. Is there some way to store a big block of xml in ANT and just call it through a variable reference or something..?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) to solve this problem. Simply define a new macro as the above invocation, but taking `file` and `output` as arguments.